# Database protected from edit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

If I see this at the bottom of SQL Server Management Studio, does this mean that I do not have permissions to edit a row?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or the column is a computed column, or populated by the `IDENTITY` property, or `ROWVERSION`, or ...

Try and edit the data in this table, you will see that all three columns are read only:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.flub
(
  i INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  x AS (i + 1),
  r ROWVERSION
);
INSERT dbo.flub DEFAULT VALUES;
```

If you share the definition of the table, we can at least tell you why if it's because of one of these reasons (we'd need more info to confirm if it's a column-level permissions issue).

Better suggestion: stop using "Open Table", "Edit Top 200 rows" or any other Excel-looking grid to modify data. Write proper DML using `UPDATE` statements - I promise you the error messages you get when you try to modify a value that you can't will be much more descriptive in almost every case. Examples from above:

```
UPDATE dbo.flub SET i = 5;
```

> Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot update identity column 'i'.

```
UPDATE dbo.flub SET x = 5;
```

> Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The column "x" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

```
UPDATE dbo.flub SET r = 0x00;
```

> Msg 272, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot update a timestamp column.

[I talk about several bugs in these UIs here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/08/20/my-management-studio-wishlist-for-sql-server-2011), and others have been reported since. [This one, for example, was just fixed in the 2012 version...](https://sqlblog.org/2007/07/29/be-careful-with-open-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting that message on one or more columns in the table, it sounds like that cell may be a computed column, which by definition does not support updates. Or, it may be an identity column which also does not support updates.

To see if it's a computed column: If you go to the table designer, you will notice no data type specified and instead (in the properties below) a Computed Column Specification. Or, in the DDL you will see an `AS` clause for the column.

Answer (score 0):

If that column you are currently trying to edit is an IDENTITY column, it will display this message.